# Name each label in the plot. Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

My data contains location points of the user. I need to plot 5 users location point.

```
df.set_index('tslot').groupby('user')['Location'].plot()
```

Which givesthe below figure as output.
[image]

How to find the color indicates specific user-id in the above figure.

```
For example:
Blue is User 1
Green is user 300
Red is user 48
```

Comment: Use `label = True` in `plot`

Comment: Hello Chris. I tried but that doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Noone can know what your issue is without [mcve], i.e. runnable code!